# Finding a String between 2 pattern python

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

So I have been learning regex in python and I have learned fairly well there is still something I can't figure out. I have a list of Strings. In that list some begin with "What" and some begin with "How" and they both end with '?'. I want all the sub string of the list of String beginning with 'What'.

Here's the pattern I tried :

```
pat = 'what + \w + \w + \w + ?'
```

but the main problem is the number of words in between are not fixed. Some have 3 and some even have 11 - 12 and If I use the or clause or if clause in regex its becoming a huge pattern with no results. Any suggestions on how to do this kind of problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need re.

```
 l = ["What blah foo?","What bar?","How blah foo?","How bar?"]

print [x for x in l if x.startswith("What")]

['What blah foo?', 'What bar?']
```

Using re:

```
l = ["What blah foo?","And What bar?","what bar?","How blah foo?","How bar?","What other foo","How other foo"]
for s in l:
    check= re.findall("^What .*\?",s,re.IGNORECASE) # find string starting with "What/what" and ending with "?"
    if check:
        print check[0]
What blah foo?
what bar?
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using re and list comprehension:

```
list = ["What blah foo?","what bar?","How blah foo?","How bar?","another What?", "some what"]

print [x for x in list if re.match(r'^what.*?', x, re.I)]
```

> ['What blah foo?', 'what bar?']